# PHP class array object method access issue

Tags: php, oop

I wrote a class

```
class User {
    private $cars = array(); //store class Car 's object

    public function getCars()
    {
        return $this->cars;
    }

    public function setCars($cars)
    {
        $this->cars = $cars;
    }
}

class Car{
    private $model;
    public function getModel()
    {
        return $this->model;
    }

    public function setModel($model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }
}
$user = new User();
$cars = $user->getCars();
$cars[0]->getModel();
```

When I try to access getModel() php report "Call to undefined method stdClass::getModel()" .
Is there the best practice to deal with such case?

Edit:I filled the getter and setter. In fact, It's generated by phpstorm.

Edit:I tried again and it works well with the demo code below. The original code is too complicated to show. Maybe I caused by my misunderstanding of copying by value and by reference of array.

Please ignore this question. sorry.

```
class User {
    private $cars = array(); //store class Car 's object

    public function getCars()
    {
        return $this->cars;
    }

    public function setCars($cars)
    {
        $this->cars = $cars;
    }
}

class Car{
    private $model;
    public function getModel()
    {
        return $this->model;
    }

    public function setModel($model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }
}

$user = new User();
$car = new Car();
$car->setModel("Ford");
$arr = $user->getCars();
array_push($arr,$car);
$user->setCars($arr);

foreach($user->getCars() as $car) {
    var_dump($car->getModel());
}
```

Comment: show your complete code, in your code there is no `getCars` or `getModel` method?

Comment: Please show the real code, you are not showing what is set for `User::cars`. According to the error message it is not an `Car` object, so you probably have an error in the code when you are setting the property. But without real code, all we can do is guess.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown your `[Getter Setter ]` code. You need to create one with something like:

```
public function setCars($val){
    $this->cars = $val;
}

public function getCars(){
    return $this->cars;
}
```

The same applies for `getModel()`